# How can I change my 'Modified — Time' column within GNOME Files in Ubuntu to show files in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM format?

Tags: nautilus, time

GNOME Files within Ubuntu 22.04 displays file modification times in 3 different formats (see image below). I would love to get all of these entries (or at least the day/month/year entries) to use YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM format (e.g. 2022-10-11 18:37 instead of 22 Oct 2022 18:37). Is this possible, or would I need to switch to a different file manager?

[image: Current Modified — Time Display within Ubuntu]